# Volume of a cylinder in paraboloid.

Tags: calculus, geometry, 3d

Find the volume lying inside the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 – 2x = 0$ and outside the paraboloid $x^2 + y^2 = 2z$, while bounded by $xy$-plane.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Tried using intigration

Comment: You could try to use cylindrical coordinates: $(x,y,z)=(\rho \cos \theta, \rho \sin \theta , z)$.

Comment: So, from the first condtion you get $\rho^2 \cos \theta^2+\rho^2 \sin \theta^2-2\rho \cos \theta \le 0 \iff  0 < \rho \le 2\cos\theta$. Using cylindrical coordinates you also have $0<z \le \rho^2/2$. Since $\rho$ is positive for defintion also $\cos \theta$ has to be positive.

Comment: Read this before you post your next question: [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803).

Comment: Alternate/ easy to follow solution:

Change of coordinates as $(x-1)=r\cos{\theta}$ and $y=r\sin{\theta}$ as the centre of the circle is xy-plane is offset to $(1,0)$

Then compute the following integral: $$\iint \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)dA$$
$$=\int^{2\pi}_{0}\int^{1}_{0}(r^2+2r\cos{\theta+1)}dr\cdot d\theta$$
$$=\frac{3{\pi}}{4}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of the paraboloid is $x^2+y^2 = 2z.$ So it is same as taking a parabola $x^2 = 2z$ where $y = 0$ or taking $y^2 = 2z$ where $x = 0$ and rotating it around $z$-axis. Here, $z \ge 0.$

The cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 2x$ can be described as a cylinder with radius $1$ and touching $yz$ plane with $ 0 \le x \le 2$ and $ -1 \le y \le 1$ and $z \ge 0$ as it is bound by $xy$ plane on the same side as paraboloid. For z = 0, it is a circle of radius 1 with center at $(1,0)$. You can also write it as $(x-1)^2+y^2 = 1.$ I hope you can now visualize it.

In polar coordinates, you can write it as

$$[{ (r, θ) | − π/2 ≤ θ ≤ π/2, 0 ≤ r ≤ 2\cos θ }]$$

And the height is bound by $z$ value of the paraboloid which is $\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2).$

You can integrate the area of the circle (A) between these bounds to find the volume.

$$\iint \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)dA$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}\int^{2\cos\theta}_{0}r^2\cdot r\cdot dr\cdot d\theta$$

$$2\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}\cos^4\theta \cdot d\theta $$

$$2\int \cos^4\theta \cdot d\theta = \frac{1}{2}\cos^3\theta\cdot \sin\theta+\frac{3}{2}\int \cos^2\theta d\theta $$$$= \frac{1}{2}\left[\cos^3\theta\cdot\sin\theta+\frac{3}{2}(\cos\theta \sin\theta+\theta)\right]$$

For ${-\pi/2}\le \theta \le {\pi/2}$, this will give a final answer of $\frac{3\pi}{4}$.